# How to call a module from inside my program

Tags: wxpython

I imagine this is a noob question, though coming from a noob ... it's warranted. I have an app where a menu item exists that I want to use to call an external module (a wx.dialog). I imported the module as such:

```
from module_name import class_name
```

Now, I'm stumped on how to start the module when I press the menu item in my wxPython app?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\SQA_log\wxGui_comPort.py", line 141, in OnConvert
dlg = Converter(*args)
NameError: global name 'args' is not defined
```

Abridged code ... for sake of brevity:
Menu bar from class:

```
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, id=1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=2)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDisp, id=3)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnServ, id=4)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDateTime, id=5)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, id=6)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnConvert, id=7)# Here is the menu item I'm using
```

The function called:

```
def OnConvert(self,e):
    dlg = Converter()
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

This is the autonomous module/class:

```
import wx

class Converter(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(350, 310))

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Convert Decimal to Hex', (20,20))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Decimal: ', (20, 80))
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Hex: ', (20, 150))
        self.dec_hex =  wx.StaticText(self, -1, '', (150, 150))
        self.sc = wx.SpinCtrl(self, -1, '',  (150, 75), (60, -1))
        self.sc.SetRange(-459, 1000)
        self.sc.SetValue(0)
        compute_btn = wx.Button(self, 1, 'Compute', (70, 250))
        compute_btn.SetFocus()
        clear_btn = wx.Button(self, 2, 'Close', (185, 250))

        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 1, self.OnCompute)
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 2, self.OnQuit)
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self,  self.OnClose)

        self.Centre()
        self.ShowModal()
        self.Destroy()


    def OnCompute(self, event):
        dec = self.sc.GetValue()
        hex1 = "%x" % dec
        self.dec_hex.SetLabel(str(hex1).upper())

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    dlog = Converter(None, 'Converter')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the menu event to a menu handler and then in the event handler, you instantiate your class. So something like this:

```
def myEventHandler(self, event):
   dlg = class_name(*args)
   dlg.ShowModal()
   dlg.Destroy()
```

See also http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/ or http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithMenus

EDIT: As is obvious, the Converter class accepts 3 arguments: self, parent and title. You have to provide those when you instantiate a dialog:

```
dlg = Converter(None, "MyTitle")
```

Here are some documentation links on dialogs and how to read tracebacks:

- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Dialog-class.html
- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/traceback/

Comment: The "*args" bit is whatever arguments you need to pass to the dialog.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any. The dialog is self contained. It just converts dec to hex.

Comment: Then it would just be dlg = class_name()

Comment: Yes, that was my reasoning initially. But, I get the error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: It would help if you actually gave us an example of your code so we could see what it looks like.

Comment: I learn something new every day ... Mike that wasn't obvious to me: When I say I'm green, I totally mean it!